# Rails, how to make redirect_to asynchronous, so it's executed before the end of the action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

In my action, I issue redirect_to and then run some computations. My code looks something like below

```
def method_in_controller:
  url = params[:url]
  redirect_to url
  computation_related_to_this_call #Some method which will take some insignificant amount of time
```

Since `redirect_to` is executed at the end of the action, it is effectively blocked until all the statements after the redirect_to statement are executed. This delays application response to user (which is redirecting). How can I get return_to acted upon without waiting for the rest of the action to complete execution?

For example if `computation_related_to_this_call` were as below, `redirect_to` executes after the 10 second sleep.

```
def computation_related_to_this_call:
  sleep(10)
```

Must I use background jobs gem (`Resque` or `Sidekiq`) or `Threading` to achieve what I am looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

Use callbacks

```
before_action :name_of_method, only: [:action_name]


def name_of_method
 ..
 do something 
 ..
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. That said, before_action does sound a bit unnatural here. The redirect is core part of the action (show). Perhaps, the processing part is less of core part and maybe I should be using after_action for the processing part and leave redirect_to in the action (show) itself?

Comment: Use after_action , if you intend to do something after show method occurs, and redirect_to should be done on show it self .

Comment: Tried, redirect_to in show method and had process method called as after_action. However, I am again see that redirect_to is being blocked until process gets completed. Any idea what might be happening?